# Strange characters in text saved Brackets

Tags: utf-8, adobe-brackets

I close it and reopen it I get some letters and strange characters, especially where words have accent.

look at an example:

**Este exto es la creaciÃ³n de mÃ­ probia autorÃ­a**

google translation

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a byte representation of your string, which is UTF-8. UTF-8 is multibyte encoding, that means that some characters (eg. those with accents) are saved as several bytes, usually starting with Ã.

Your application probably doesn't understand that the string is UTF-8 and prints it as byte sequence. You should use a different text editor which will be able to display your UTF-8 text correctly.